# How To Print Nearest numbers to a given input?

Tags: python

we have this series:
1,1,2,4,7,13,24...
(after the 3rd,every number is given by sum of the previous three numbers)
actually how we can print the nearest numbers to an input?
for example users give 10,and we should print 7 and 13, or he give 20,and we should print 24,i appreciate your help.

here is the example:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK1xv.jpg

Comment: Will not do your lab for you. Show us you code, please. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Standard math: `min(sequence, key = lambda i: abs(i - number))`

Comment: However, this only selects one number in the event that two fit the mold.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution will be suitable for your problem:

```
def three_fibonacci(stack,n):
    stack.append(stack[-1] + stack[-2] + stack[-3])
    if n < stack[-1]:
        print stack[-1]
        print stack[-2]
    else:
        three_fibonacci(stack,n)

start_array = [1,1,2]
three_fibonacci(start_array,20)
```

Comment: n=float(input())

a=1
b=1
c=2
d=0
while d<n:
    v=c
    d=a+b+c
    a=b
    b=c
    c=d
f=abs(d-n)
g=abs(b-n)

if f>g:
    print(b)

elif g>f:
    print(d)
elif f==g:
    print(d)
    print(b)
i worked it out by this code,since we havent reached to operands on lists in our class and i dont know how to use them,anyway thank you for  your answer.